# Trouble understanding the basics of a dual space and solving for its basis - Example from *Linear Algebra by Friedberg*

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

This example comes from "*Linear Algebra by Friedberg, et.al - pg. 120*". It is example 4. The following is a screenshot of the example:

[image]

for reference the function $f_{i}$ is defined as $f_{i}(x) = a_{i}$, where

$$[x]_{\beta} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n})$$

is the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the basis $\beta$.

The mechanics of the problem I understand, but it is the reasoning where I'm having an issue. I have the following questions:

1. I could see why we would need to determine a formula for $f_{1}$ because up to now it is just an arbitrary component, but how we go about it is confusing. I see why $1 = f_{1}(2,1)$, it is because with respect to our basis $\beta$ it is the first component. But then why do we rewrite $(2,1)$ in terms of the standard basis vectors?
2. I see how $f_{1}(e_{1}) = -1$ and $f_{1}(e_{2}) = 3$, but now using this idea are we then treating the vector $(x,y)$ as "scalars" when applied to $f_{1}$?

All of the same of course follows for $f_{2}$, but clarifying $f_{1}$ will take care of that. I think my main issue is with why rewriting the vector in terms of the standard basis vectors and how we are getting a formula from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Another way of finding $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ (without using the standard basis) would be to consider an arbitrary $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and writing
   $$ (x, y) = f_{1}(x, y)(2, 1) + f_{2}(x, y)(3,1). $$
   This gives us two equations for $f_{1}(x, y)$ and $f_{2}(x, y)$. After solving them, we get that $f_{1}(x, y) = 3y - x$ and $f_{2}(x, y) = x - 2y$.

   Once we have a basis $\beta$ for $V$, the dual basis $\beta^{*}$ gives us the coordinates of any $v \in V$ with respect to $\beta$. Similarly, $\beta$ gives us the coordinates of any functional in $V^{*}$ with respect to $\beta^{*}$. To be more specific:

   Let $\beta = (v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n})$ be a basis for $V$ and $\beta^{*} = (f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n})$ the corresponding dual basis.
   Then, for any $v \in V$,
   $$ v = f_{1}(v) v_{1} + \ldots + f_{n}(v) v_{n} .$$
   Similarly, if $f \in V^{*}$,
   $$ f = f(v_{1}) f_{1} + \ldots + f(v_{n}) f_{n} .$$
2. It is a consequence of linearity:
   $$ f_{1}(x, y) = f_{1}( x(1, 0) + y(0,1) ) = xf_{1}(1, 0) + yf_{1}(0,1). $$

Comment: Question with regards to what you stated in your theorem. If we have a basis $\beta = \{v_{1}, \dots, v_{n})$ for $V$, why would we go through the trouble of using the $f_{i}$ to find our coefficients if we can do it explicitly already? I'm guessing this probably has to do with simplicity of some sort of calculation if we had functions $f_{i}$ to extract the coefficients without having to solve the system of linear equations using row reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $V^*$ is the space of linear functionals  i.e. linear functions from $V\to \mathbb{F}$ (in this case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$) so that treats your second question.

Now note that by definition, we must have that $f_1(2, 1) = 1, f_1(3, 1)= 0$ because of how we ordered the basis. We want to explicitly determine what the function is. Now since it has to be $\textbf{linear}$, we want to write it in terms of its components because in terms of $e_1$, this will tell its $x$-component and likewise for $e_2$ for the $y$-component. Note that $f(c, 0)= cf(1, 0)$.